# Polymer convenient way to get model changes

Tags: javascript, polymer, data-modeling

I'm binding some data by a one-way method and edit some hidden field, and want to get all data, what is changed and compare it to the original data.

This is easily done in OpenUI or ExtJS, where I can achieve this by API, and I only have to send changed data to the server.

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We will not do all your homework. You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve the problem at your own.